# PHP DateTime diff creates DateInterval with negative hours

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I recently discovered a strange behavior of DateTime diff().
I just tried to calculate the difference between the following dates:

```
$first = new DateTime('2016-07-05T00:00:00');
$second = new DateTime('2016-12-30T23:59:59');
$interval = $first->diff($second);
echo $interval->h;
```

The strange thing is that this will output:

```
-1
```

That's a little bit confusing as I thought the public attributes of DateInterval are positive.
Now if I try to create such a DateInterval by myself:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P5M26DT-1H59M59S');
```

This will fail as negative values for hours are not allowed.

Is this behavior normal? If yes, how can i safely convert a DateInterval to string/from string (e.q. for storing in a DB)?

Comment: You have a daylight savings shift in that timeframe don't you

Comment: Yeah i think thats the issue! If the first date is inside the daylight saving time, the problem occurs. But nevertheless shouldn't PHP smart enough to decrease the amount of dates by 1 and increase the hours by 24, so we get a positive hours value again?

Comment: My guess would be that more people would complain if the days value wasn't what they expected than if the hours value was -1

Comment: Did you get this result in Linux SO?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes i used Linux, but i think this will occur on every OS.
I think i know understand why the -1 is necessary. See http://www.mendoweb.be/blog/php-dateinterval-dst-change/